# Mi app mobile funciona en el Emulador, pero desde el celular da error. Cómo parametrizar propiedades Network?

Tags: genexus

Tengo una app mobile compuesta por 1 objeto Menu, 1 objeto Panel,  y  4 Procedures que son llamados desde el objeto Panel para realizar lógica a partir de los datos ingresados por el usuario sobre el Panel o de los datos obtenidos del Client Storage   .
Esta aplicación no se conecta a ninguna base de datos externa a través de un servicio REST, ni tampoco utiliza una base interna SQLite.
Solamente inserta y recupera los valores de unos Keys del dentro del objeto Client Storage dentro del celular.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo debería dejar parametrizadas las Propiedades del objeto Menu y del Objeto Panel?
La propiedad “Network\Connectivity Support” si la dejo en ONLINE en ambos objetos,
Y en los Procedures dejo “Network\Connectivity Support” igual a INHERIT la aplicación compila y se abre dentro del Emulador. Pero al probarlo en un celular da error
**Error de red tratando de comunicarse con el servidor (recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)).**

La propiedad “Network\Connectivity Support” si la dejo en OFFLINE en ambos objetos,
Y en los Procedures dejo “Network\Connectivity Support” igual a INHERIT la aplicación da error en la compilación pero no sé que propiedad adicional corregir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por el error de compilacion intenta un rebuild, parece que no se genero un Sdt. Si eso no soluciona, envia export (xpz) de tu caso a soporte. Gracias

Comment: Lo pude solucionar. Deje tanto el Menu como el Panel SD con la propiedad "Conectivity Support" = Online, y los 4 procedures los puse con "Inherit". Luego,   parado en "Preferences\.Net Enviroment\Back end\ Default (C# Web)", fui a la solapa  "Execution" y ahi solo active la propiedad Deploy to Cloud.  Compile todo (F5), y me funcionó tanto en el Emulador como cuando lleve la apk a un celular.